# pass a variable with set_by_lua_file

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

very simple question for most of you I suppose, but I can't find any answers.
I don't know lua at all, I just need this for work :)

I have a line in my nginx.conf like so:

`set_by_lua_file $instance_address conf/some_file.lua "user:";`

What I need to do basically is set my variable `instance_address` from my file `some_file.lua` and also passing the variable `user:*` for this example. Does this work ? Can I access the variable inside `some_file.lua` then ? How ?

I've tried with `$0`, `$1`, `arg[0]` and `arg[1]` but it didn't work

Cheers !

Comment: I think you should set some nginx variable like `set $user "user:"` in your nginx config and then use its value as `ngx.var.user` in your lua code.

Comment: Oh that's amazing ! Thanks I'll let you know if it works !

Comment: it worked @IvanShatsky ! Can you put what you said as an answer so I can mark it as resolved ? Thanks :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to pass some value to the lua script from nginx configuration, you can set some variable to the required value, e.g.

```
set $user "user:";
```

and then use it in the lua script via [`ngx.var.user`](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxvarvariable).